# Swift: replace character in string - without stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: string, replace, swift

OK, so say I have a `String` like

```
let myString = "my string: hello"
```

and I want to replace ":" with ",". I got as far as this:

```
let characters = map(Array(myString), {$0 == ":" ? "," : $0})
```

Which returns a `MapCollectionView<Array<Character>, Character>`. Is there a simple way to convert this back into a `String`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not for using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString ?

Comment: None at all, other than curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this? Combine all characters to a string by "reducing" them with the `+`
operator:

```
let str = Array(characters).reduce("", combine: +)
println(str)
// Output: my string, hello
```

*Update:* An alternative (perhaps nicer) solution:

```
var str = ""
str.extend(characters)
```

Using `extend()`, the string replacement could be done without an intermediate `Array`:

```
let myString = "my string: hello" as String
var myNewString = ""
myNewString.extend(map(myString.generate(), {$0 == ":" ? "," : $0} ))
```

Comment: @AshleyMills: You are welcome! - But have a look at the update, perhaps you can use that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Martin R's answer, I reduced my code down to:

```
let myString = "my string: hello" as String
let myNewString = Array(myString).reduce("") { $0 + (String($1) == ":" ? "," : String($1)) }
```

---

*Update*

As of Xcode 6.2 beta, the following now works:

```
let myString = "my string: hello"
let result = String(map(Array(myString)) {$0 == ":" ? "," : $0})

// Output: my string, hello
```

Answer (score 0):

What about finding the Substring you want (could also be words) and then replace them:

```
var aString = "Replace the letter e with *"

import Foundation
while let range: Range<String.Index> =  aString.rangeOfString("e") {
    aString.replaceRange(range, with: "*")
}
```

*works with Xcode 7.0.1*