# string replace substring without NSString API

Tags: swift

I would like to be able to find and replace occurrences of a substring in a native Swift string without bridging to the NS class. How can I accomplish this?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529612/swift-replace-character-in-string-without-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstrin), as that question is about replacing a single character. This question is about finding and replacing a substring, which may contain many characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: replace character in string - without stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529612/swift-replace-character-in-string-without-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstrin)

Comment: really? why all the down votes? This is not a duplicate and based on the answers, non trivial

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I am curious to know the reason for not using Foundation? Sure it's not pure Swift, but is there a reason to swap one line of code for 20?

Comment: @Adrian avoiding `NSString–String` duality if any reason beyond “I’d rather not import a massive legacy Apple lib if I’m not developing on an Apple platform” was ever needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generic and pure Swift approach

```
func splitBy<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ s:T, by:T)->[T] where T.Iterator.Element:Equatable {
    var tmp = T()
    var res = [T]()
    var i:T.IndexDistance = 0
    let count = by.count

    var pc:T.Iterator.Element {
        get {
            i %= count
            let idx = by.index(by.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            return by[idx]
        }
    }

    for sc in s {
        if sc != pc {
            i = 0
            if sc != pc {
            } else {
                i = i.advanced(by: 1)
            }
        } else {
            i = i.advanced(by: 1)
        }
        tmp.append(sc)
        if i == count {
            tmp.removeSubrange(tmp.index(tmp.endIndex, offsetBy: -i)..<tmp.endIndex)
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp.removeAll()
        }
    }

    res.append(tmp)
    return res
}

func split(_ s:String, by:String)->[String] {
    return splitBy(s.characters, by: by.characters).map(String.init)
}


extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self.Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    func split(by : Self)->[Self]  {
        return splitBy(self, by: by)
    }
}
```

how to use it?

```
let str = "simple text where i would like to replace something with anything"
let pat = "something"
let rep = "anything"

let s0 = str.characters.split(by: pat.characters).map(String.init)
let res = s0.joined(separator: rep)
print(res) // simple text where i would like to replace anything with anything

let res2 = split(str, by: pat).joined(separator: rep)
print(res2) // simple text where i would like to replace anything with anything

let arr = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
let p = [4,1]
print(arr.split(by: p)) // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method without `Foundation`:**

```
extension String {
    func replacing(_ oldString: String, with newString: String) -> String {

        guard !oldString.isEmpty, !newString.isEmpty else { return self }

        let charArray = Array(self.characters)
        let oldCharArray = Array(oldString.characters)
        let newCharArray = Array(newString.characters)

        var matchedChars = 0
        var resultCharArray = [Character]()

        for char in charArray {
            if char == oldCharArray[matchedChars] {
                matchedChars += 1
                if matchedChars == oldCharArray.count {
                    resultCharArray.append(contentsOf: newCharArray)
                    matchedChars = 0
                }
            } else {
                for i in 0 ..< matchedChars {
                    resultCharArray.append(oldCharArray[i])
                }
                if char == oldCharArray[0] {
                    matchedChars = 1
                } else {
                    matchedChars = 0
                    resultCharArray.append(char)
                }
            }
        }

        return String(resultCharArray)

    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let myString = "Hello World HelHelloello Hello HellHellooo"
print(myString.replacing("Hello", with: "Hi"))
```

Output:

```
Hi World HelHiello Hi HellHioo
```

---

**Method using `Foundation`:**

You can use the `replacingOccurrences` method on the `String` struct.

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let newString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "World", with: "Everyone")
print(newString) // prints "Hello Everyone"
```